# Intercept Thead end in a Web App

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee

given the code bellow how can I log resquest time just when the thread ends to get just one final RequestTime?

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    new ClientRequestContextHolder();
    logger.info("request filter ("+ ClientRequestContextHolder.getContext().getAttribute("uniqueId") +") started");
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    logger.info("request filter ("+ ClientRequestContextHolder.getContext().getAttribute("uniqueId") +") finished");
    long st = (long)ClientRequestContextHolder.getContext().getAttribute("request_start");
    logger.info("RequestTime: " + customFormat("###,###.###",(System.nanoTime() - st)) + "ns");

}
```

my current output looks like this

```
INFO : com.app.context.ClientRequestContextHolder - initialized
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - request filter (34) started
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - request filter (34) started
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - request filter (34) finished
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - RequestTime: 7,958,694ns
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - request filter (34) started
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - request filter (34) started
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - request filter (34) started
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - request filter (34) finished
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - RequestTime: 12,657,404ns
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - request filter (34) started
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - request filter (34) finished
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - RequestTime: 13,942,554ns
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - request filter (34) finished
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - RequestTime: 14,579,297ns
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - request filter (34) started
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - request filter (34) finished
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - RequestTime: 16,428,276ns
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - request filter (34) started
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - request filter (34) finished
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - RequestTime: 17,329,786ns
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - request filter (34) started
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - request filter (34) finished
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - RequestTime: 42,787,490ns
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - request filter (34) finished
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - RequestTime: 43,226,233ns
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - request filter (34) finished
INFO : com.app.filters.ClientRequestFilter - RequestTime: 45,455,568ns
```

Comment: Are you saying a single execution of this code cause the below output?

Comment: Those are the other web resources being polled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it.

since filter chaing is recursive I just added a deep control on it. At the final, if the deep is 0 then I calculate an print the result.